# Isolated points within a compact space.

Tags: analysis

Here's an exercise in normed spaces that I can't get my head around.
It reads as follows: 
"Let X be a compact space equipped with norm d. If X is countable, then the set of isolated points in X is both open and dense."
Just point me in the right direction.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You meant "metric", not "norm", right? Norms live on vector spaces - there are no compact or countable vector spaces. (Everyone else: Yes, I know that last statement is false. _Context_...)

Comment: Yes that's right, X is only a metric.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint for the "open" part: What's the _definition_ of "isolated point"? Any union of open sets is open...

Comment: So, if J is the set of isolated points, then for x in J we have a>0 such that B(x,a) is only {x}, which is contained in J. Taking the union for all x (which are at most countable, which doesn't really matter)  we get an open set! Thanks!

Comment: The density part eludes me still...

Answer (score 3):

You've already figured out why the set of isolated points $I$ is open.

To show $I$ is dense:  Because your space is countable, you can enumerate the *non*-isolated points $x_1, x_2,$ and so on.  Define $U_0 = X$ and for all natural numbers $n$, let $U_{n+1} = U_n \setminus \{x_n\}$.  Use induction to show $U_n$ is open and dense for all $n$.  Then use the Baire Category theorem.

Comment: You can simplify it slightly by just letting $U_n=X\setminus\{x_n\}$.